# Post text string to url

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="includes/search.php" method="get">
    <input name="search" type="text" class="search" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

I want user to type text in textfield and when he hits enter it will paste it in URL.

Currently url is: http://randomsite.com/includes/search.php?search=adsasd

But it should be like this: http://randomsite.com/beta/match/adsasd

Comment: You need htaccess `mod_rewrite`. Search for that keyword on `SO`

Comment: Okay. How can I remove "?search=" before value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently submitting the form as a GET request to the includes/search.php page.

Try calling a JavaScript function instead:

```
<form id="search-form" onsubmit="return performSearch()">
  <input name="search" type="text" class="search" id="search-query" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Then collect the information from each field, and redirect to the desired URL in that function:

```
function makeSearch()
{
  var searchQuery = document.getElementById("search-query").value;
  var searchURL = 'http://randomsite.com/beta/match/' + searchQuery;
  window.location.assign(searchURL);
  return false;
}
```

NOTE: Untested, but should work or be very close to a solution.